# How come I can't see my android device anymore on Android Studio?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, adb, android-debug

Just yesterday I updated Android Studio. Before I updated it everything was working fine, meaning I was able to use my Samsung Galaxy S4 to debug my apps with no problem. After the update, Android Studio no longer sees my device when I try to debug.

Furthermore when I type in `adb devices` on my terminal (I am using Ubuntu), my device doesn't show in the `list of devices attached`. Please help! I'm been trying to find a solution but most only talk about reinstalling drivers for Windows users.

Also, not sure if this may help but when I updated Android Studio, I was prompted to move the SDK folder to another location.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score -1):

Google's usb driver is located within the Android SDK folders, so perhaps in moving that, your computer can not find the driver anymore.

Try going to Device Manager (the windows one from the Control Panel), look for your mobile device and choose to re-install the driver, choosing one from your own disk.
It should be located at `~\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

Comment: I am not using Windows, I have Ubuntu install on my laptop. Is there a way I can do something like this on a Linux-based OS?

Comment: I'm sure there is...
The idea is the same, just check if moving your SDK folder has had any effect on the installed driver.